# mac eclipse oxygen unable to import gnu.io.SerialPort

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, importerror

I could say I'm new to Java and Eclipse.

I've been given a simple code in Java to imported into Eclipse Oxygen.

The problem is that Eclipse complains about being unable to import gnu.io.SerialPort and gnu.io.ComPortIdentifier.

I'm working on a MAC, not sure about the O.S. that uses the person that gave me the code.

Can you help me to fix this issue?

Lots of thanks

Answer (score 0):

Googling I've found the following site:   [http://jlog.org/rxtx-mac.html][1]

There I've downloaded the files:

- RXTXcomm.jar
- librxtxSerial.jnilib

And copied them into /Library/Java/Extensions.

Then I've closed and reopened Eclipse and now the import of gnu.io.* wors fine.

Thanks